# Intuition on C++ situations where an an unknown number of objects of a custom class will be needed at runtime

Tags: c++, oop, heap-memory, raii

Everything below has to do with situations where a developer makes a custom C++ class (I have in mind something like `OnlyKnowDemandAtRuntime` below)... and there can be no way of knowing how many instances/objects "the user" will need during runtime.

Question 1: As a sanity check, is it fair to say that in Case One below, RAII is being used to manage the "dynamic" usage of `OnlyKnowDemandAtRuntime`?

Question 2: Is it correct to say that in case two, RAII isn't the first option that comes to mind simply because it is inconvenient (possibly a major understatement here) to hack up a way to wrap the nodes of a tree in an STL container? And, therefore, it is simpler to just use new and destructor/delete (or smart pointers) here, rather than scramble for a way to have the standard library manage memory for us. Note: Nothing here is a question about whether trees are often used in day to day work; rather, everything in this post is about the intuition behind the decision making one must do when using C++ to create objects at runtime. Note: Of course smart pointers are themselves part of the library, and of course they handle memory for us just as the library containers do... but for the purposes of this question I'm putting smart pointers and `new` on the same footing: Because my question is about the limits on the abilities of the STL containers to have more and more instances of something like `OnlyKnowDemandAtRuntime` inserted into them at runtime, while also being able to handle the relationships between said instances (without adding lots of logic to keep track of where things are in the container).

Question 3: If 1 and 2 are reasonable enough, then would a fair summary be this: [When a developer makes a custom class but doesn't know how many objects of it will be needed during runtime], either...

- Wrap the objects in an STL container when the structure between said objects is "trackable" with the STL container being used (or perhaps trackable with the STL container being used plus some reasonably simple extra logic), or
- Explicitly use the heap to build the objects with new and destructor/delete, or smart pointers, and manually build the structure "between" said objects (as in `left_` and `right_` of Case Two below).

Quick reminder, this isn't about whether we need to build trees in day to day work with C++. Also, (and I suppose this is already clear to anyone who would answer this question) this is not about "use the heap when an object is too big for the stack or when an object needs a lifetime beyond the scope in which it was created".

Case One:

```
  // This is the class "for" which an unknown of objects will be created during runtime
  class OnlyKnowDemandAtRuntime {
   public:
    OnlyKnowDemandAtRuntime(int num) : number_(num) {};
   private:
    int number_;
  };

  // This is the class where an a priori unknown number of `OnlyKnowDemandAtRuntime` objects are created at runtime.
  class SomeOtherClass {
   public:
    void NeedAnotherOnlyKnownAtRuntime(int num) {
      v_only_know_demand_at_runtime_.emplace_back(num);
    }
   private:
    std::vector<OnlyKnowDemandAtRuntime> v_only_know_demand_at_runtime_;
  }
```

Case Two:

```
  // This is the class "for" which an unknown of objects will be created during runtime
  class Node{
   public:
    Node(int value) : value_(value), left_(nullptr), right_(nullptr) {};
   private:
    int value_;
    Node *left_;
    Node *right_;
    friend class Tree;
  };

  // This is the class where an a priori unknown number of `Node` objects are created at runtime.
  class Tree {
   public:
    ~Tree() { // Traverse tree and `delete` every `Node *` //}
    void Insert(int value) {
      Node *new_node = new Node(value); 
      ThisMethodPlacesNewNodeInTheAppropriateLeafPosition(new_node);
    }
   private:
    Node *root;
  }
```

Comment: RAII is a technique for ensuring that dynamically allocated resources are appropriately released exactly once - not that those resources are released in some defined order.    As such, it is a valid approach in your second case.   The only reason you're "intuitively" avoiding RAII in your second case is that you haven't thought enough about the life cycle of your nodes, so the order of release matters to you.  As a counter-example to your statements, some of the standard containers are implemented as linked lists, and RAII was a key consideration in their design.

Comment: @Peter I can't really speak for anyone else reading this in the future, but for me personally... it would be useful to see an example of a simple way to keep all the nodes of, say, a binary tree in a normal STL container without adding considerable complexity to keep track of things. Such an example would perhaps be a slightly less general response than what I was hoping for, but it might nonetheless get to the heart of much of what I had in mind when I posted this.

Comment: I think you're conflating issues.   The whole point of linked list or some tree data structure is that they keep track of their nodes so (among other things) can manage lifetime of the nodes.   The (non-contiguous) standard containers ARE implemented as linked list or tree structures, so they keep track of their nodes, and can (and do) manage their lifetime.   They don't use some other container to manage the nodes for them.

Comment: @Peter Now I understand. Yup I know all STL containers keep track of themselves and manage their lifetimes. All things related to my use of RAII, & Case One above, (never mind the arbitrary choice to use vector rather than, say, list there) is about that: C++ managing memory for us. But are there clear examples where a ["data"] structure we make at runtime from a custom class does not lend itself well to wrapping each object in a STL container [where C++ manages memory for us], leaving us to use dynamic memory (new etc.) explicitly? Of course we can clean up after ourselves in such cases.

Comment: Sorry but “smart pointers” are RAII too. So your questions 2 and 3 aren’t very self-consistent.

Comment: Short answer: no. Plenty of programmers think "my approach is unique, so I can do better by managing resources explicitly" but most are wrong. The C++ standard specifies the standard containers (vectors, lists, maps, smart pointers, etc) as a complete toolbox (within current state of knowledge). The number of programmers who *think* they can beat the standard library is much less than the number of true (verifiable) innovators who actually can. If clear cases like you seek existed, the innovation would already be well advanced - and the standard itself would be updated accordingly.

Comment: My point is that your questions 2 and 3 are based on the premise that there must be low hanging fruit that have been missed by numerous researchers in a range of specialised and generalised areas (data structures, algorithms, etc) of computer science, so are not included in the C++ standard (or the specification of other programming languages/libraries where language designers also draw on the state of current knowledge and available research literature). The reality is that such low hanging fruit (a simple innovation for the plucking that nobody has spotted) is quite rare.

Comment: @numzero Thanks for pointing that out! I just made an edit clarifying that the work done under the hood with smart pointers (which absolutely is on the same footing as containers in the sense that it handles allocation and deallocation for us) is not part of the fundamental query about the limits of using containers (without excessive additional logic) to handle lots of instances that must be created at runtime.

Comment: @Peter I think you are on to something. This wouldn't be the first time I was accused of seemingly dismissing what the giants have left us with to date. But whenever that happens (including here), it is only because I don't deeply enough understand the state of affairs... in this case vis a vis the limitations on using containers for wrapping "our own" objects that need to be instantiated over and over at runtime. Or, to put it closer to your words, I don't have any intuition around what types of things are yet to be discovered in relation to 2 and 3.

Comment: @peter Actually, I have a quick question about your response that might help clarify things a bit: Is it fair to say that you would agree with this.... we either can use a library container to hold "our own" objects that need to be instantiated over and over at runtime; or, if we can't, then we are left in the "yet to be discovered" camp... and, therefore, we must either use new (smart pointers are fine but they aren't part of the logic underlying my query) each time, like in the tree from case Two above,  or use a container and add extra "structure logic" to keep track of things.

Comment: No, I disagree (or it's difficult to postulate cases where I'd agree). Firstly, using standard containers does not necessarily mean instantiating "over and over at runtime" - choosing the container type based on operations to be done on it typically avoids such things so your "if we can't" case is unlikely. A container includes, by its nature, "structure logic" to keep track of the things it contains while meeting specified (by the standard) performance requirements. So using a standard container and needing additional "structure logic" is more often a sign of using the wrong container

Comment: *"Question 1 ... 2 ... 3"*: you should limit your post to one question only. Now it is too broad.

Comment: @trincot Sure thing. I agree. Obviously you have been around the block here based on your reputation... so may I run this by you: Would this seem like a clear question to post in favor of all the above.... "Assume (based on known conditions for our application) we are making some C++ application where, at runtime, more and more instances/objects of a custom class we are writing will be instantiated [again, we're talking about instantiated at runtime by necessity]. In such a situation, are there compelling reasons to NOT use a container from the STL to hold all such objects/instances"?

Comment: @Peter Sorry but... no. C++ STL is very lacking. Remember how late did it get hashmap. And it still lacks multiindex. And it lacks ability to use object member as a key, forcing duplicating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to your literal questions but you might find this useful.

1. Smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` are most basic RAII classes.
2. Using RAII is the only reasonably sane way to ensure exception safety.
3. In your particular example, I’d use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` specifically. With arbitrary graph that’d be more complicated ofc.

Also,

> makes a custom C++ class but doesn't know how many objects of it will be needed during runtime.

That’s highly unspecific. It is important that you have a container (be it `SomeOtherClass` or `Tree` or whatever) that manages these objects. Otherwise, things may become really really complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Hopefully the change I made to the quote you used (at the very beginning of my post) helped clarify things. Regarding smart pointers, I added a blurb at the end of question 2 that hopefully covers the fact that the memory management done by smart pointers is somehow not part of what I'm wrestling with... more on this in the 7 or so comments in the back and forth with Peter in the comments above.

Comment: For an arbitrary graph I would have the graph object deals with the lifetime, and the nodes don't participate in owning each other. One might even write a tree like that for caching reasons

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for that comment! I think you are saying that for an arbitrary graph you would architect things in the spirit of case two above where, within the graph or tree object, memory management is done explicitly (with new and delete/destructor or with smart pointers) "for" the nodes. Is that correct? That is what I would do too by the way, and indeed learning that such a pattern is THE pattern in such cases would go a long way toward answering my question (but please do let me know if my restatement of your reply is not what you meant).

Comment: @tarstevs, no the graph would have e.g. a `std::vector<Node>` member

Comment: @Caleth lol :) Okay fine. imo that IS the good way to do things whenever "possible" (and I at least think that's what Bjarne talks about all the time during his conference talks in the last 5ish years when he encourages people to let C++ containers manage memory lifecycles)... BUT... doesn't this mean that for trees and graphs you have to write some serious logic [and create some extra data strucutre(s)] to manage the relationships between the nodes in your library container? The answer just has to be yes. Right? So fine if the answer is yes... that will help clarify things a lot.

Comment: No, the nodes will just have non owning raw pointers. You just don't have `new` and `delete` alongside that

Comment: `std::vector<Node>` and raw pointers aren’t very compatible, if you need to add/remove nodes. Something like `std::list<Node>` or even `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` will be better. Still, it’s all about tradeoffs.

Comment: @numzero Yeah, It seems to me there is confusion, throughout the comments here (and below the main post), between these two different contexts [to illustrate, I'll take the situation of a tree class using nodes from an external node class]:
Cntxt 1: [Tree class w/ nodes from external node class] where the node objects/instances created at runtime in the tree class are in a STL container
Contxt 2: [Tree class w/ nodes from external node class] where the node objects/instances created at runtime in the tree class are in a smart pointer (or handled w/ new/delete-destructor).

Comment: [Regarding above] I feel like for Cntxt 1 the tradeoffs are:
Good-- Easy to handle all nodes w/ RAII using a container.
Bad-- Structure/behavior of tree might call for considerable logic/structure to be added to "handle" using said container.

And for cntxt 2 the tradeoffs are:
Good-- Normal DS/Alg textbook pattern is all that's needed
Bad-- C++ comes with some risk when making tons of objects [here, nodes] on the heap... (here it's not much of a problem assuming correct smart pointer RAII use, but the general container vs. indvdl object topic is a tradeoff to be aware of nonetheless).